# AppCode autocomplete not showing correct results

Tags: appcode, app-code

AppCode's autocomplete is showing some strange behaviour on my side that I cant seem to figure out. There are two issues I'm currently facing:

1. Auto complete results are missing or incorrect, in the case below I'm trying to create a CGRect, but only get shown one constructor:

[image]

2. No autocomplete what so ever. In the case below it will not auto complete any functions or properties on UIView.frame. Incidentally, if I create a CGRect and try and autocomplete on that variable, it will show results :

[image]

CoreGraphics is the first framework I'm working on where this seems to be a problem. This happens whether I add an import to the top of the file of not.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Are you still having this problem?